# Try recover get vs Try match

Tags: scala

In order to catch exception, I can use Try recover get:

```
Try(op) recover {
  case e: FooException => log; default
} get
```

Edit: or `fold` as pointed out in the comment for Scala 2.12+

or I can use Try match:

```
Try(op) match {
  case Success(v) => v
  case Failure(e: FooException) => log; default
  case Failure(e)=> throw e
}
```

What is the difference between these two? Which one is more idiomatic? What is the reasoning? Is there any performance implication?

Comment: I've always liked `fold()`, but that's just me.

Comment: @jwvh That requires 2.12 while we are using 2.11... But yes that is better because it is consistent with other mappable types.

Comment: This [similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/449td4/fold_or_pattern_matching_with_an_option/) may help. Based on Odersky's answer, my guess is that match is the way to go.

Comment: `.get` is a code smell

Comment: imo `try{}catch{}` is most readable for simple example like yours if you just want a value. `Try()`, should be used if you want to call your function recursively like `divide` example in the doc, or map it with a default value something like Try(f) recover {...} map(g).

Comment: Using get method of Try[T] and Option[T] is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` version is better. There are three possible outcomes (value, default, exception) and the `match` version makes this clear whereas the `recover` version is more obscure. The `recover` version also has a bare `get` which is usually a bad sign. `match` is also likely to perform better, though the cost of either version will be small compared to the work in `Try(op)`.