# Streamlining Try.recover

Tags: scala

A pattern that that I see with some frequency in Scala is "Try unwrapping" which usually looks like this:

```
Try {
  input.charAt(100)    // Some error-prone calculation
} match {
  case Success(c) => c // just unwrap the value
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(e)         // log the exception
    '?'                // and provide a default value
}
```

This code is fine, but I'm a little bothered by the `case Success(c) => c`, which is basically just an identity transformation (a.k.a. noise). The soul of the transformation is the error mapping function that logs the exception and provides a default value, and that's what I want to bring to the foreground.

I can see two alternatives that get rid of the identity transform:

We could use the `recover` method:

```
Try {
  input.charAt(100)    // Some error-prone calculation
} recover { e =>
    println(e)         // log the exception
    '?'                // and provide a default value
} get
```

but `recover` produces a `Try[T]` (which is guaranteed to be a `Success`). That has to be unwrapped with a dangling `get` (which also needs need `postFixOps` in this style).

We could also use `getOrElse`, but this doesn't allow us to log the exception.

```
Try {
  "input".charAt(100) // Some error-prone calculation
} getOrElse { 
  // println(e)       // We don't have access to the exception and can't log it
  'a'                 // provide a default value.
}
```

What I would really like is an `unwrap` or `recover++` method like

```
def unwrap[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): U
```

that either unwraps the T from the Success or unwraps the Throwable from failure and transforms it to a U with the partial function.

The easiest way I can see to do that would be to wrap the `recover/get` pipeline in an extension method that I add to `Try`, but that also sounds like overkill.

Does anyone have a slick way to implement this behavior?

P.S. I found this related question that suggests that leans towards pattern matching, but I want to see if anything better has come around in the last 5 years - [Try recover get vs Try match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065278/try-recover-get-vs-try-match)

Comment: You could use `fold` to reduce some of the noise, but you still need to provide the identity.

Comment: The extension method doesn't sound that overkill to me. We do it in some of our apps. Agree that I would love such a method to be implemented in the standard library, not sure if it has already been suggested and rejected for good reasons or not ‍♂️

Comment: I'm thinking that that extension method is probably my best bet at this point. I got really close with `ApplicativeError.handleError` but no cigar. https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicativemonaderror.html#typeclass-definition-1

Answer (score 0):

I've used the recover pattern to catch and log errors. You can also just re-throw the exception (or a different exception) from the recover block, like in this simple Json parsing code:

```
Try {
  (parse(json) \ "something").extractOrElse("default")
}.recover({
  case exception: Exception => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Invalid JSON: ${exception.getMessage}")
}).get
```